# stop progressbar from another class when it started from mainActivity

Tags: android, progress-bar

Is there any way to stop the progress bar from other class which is started in mainActivity

Kindly find the code
I am starting the progress bar in the main activity and then calling the method of other java class
where I am inserting data in firebase
I just want that after firebase insertion is successful progress bar should stop
but didn't find any way to do that

```
public class ProductDetails extends AppCompatActivity {
    ProgressBar progressbar;
    Button btn;
    FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_product_details);
        
        progressbar = findViewById(R.id.btnprogressbar);
        btn = findViewById(R.id.submit_btn);
        firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                progressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                submitForm();
            }
        });
    }

    private void submitForm() {
        FormDetailsServices formDetailsServices = new FormDetailsServices(ProductDetails.this);
        FormDTO formDTO=generateForDTO();
        formDetailsServices.submitForm(formDTO,firebaseDatabase);
    }
}
```

My FormDetailsServices:

```
public class FormDetailsServices {
    Context context;
    final String TAG = "FormDetailsServices";

    public FormDetailsServices(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public Context getContext() {
        return context;
    }

    public void setContext(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }
    
    public void submitForm(FormDTO formDTO,FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase) {

        firebaseDatabase
            .getReference()
            .child("test")
            .setValue(formDTO)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {

                Log.d(TAG,"form submitted Successfully");
                
               //here i want to stop progressbar 
               
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Log.d(TAG,"form submittion Failed exception msg= " + e.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Everything is working fine its getting inserted to Firebase but progressbar is still visible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an interface in FormDetailsServices class and implement it to your main class, and then you can hide the progress bar by calling its methods in main class as below -

```
public class ProductDetails extends AppCompatActivity implements FormDetailsServices.OnFormSubmissionListener{
ProgressBar progressbar;
Button btn;
FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
OnFormSubmissionListener listener;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_product_details);
    
    progressbar = findViewById(R.id.btnprogressbar);
    btn = findViewById(R.id.submit_btn);
    firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            progressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            submitForm();
        }
    });
}

private void submitForm() {
    FormDetailsServices formDetailsServices = new 
    FormDetailsServices(ProductDetails.this);
    formDetailsServices.setOnFormSubmissionListener(this);
    FormDTO formDTO=generateForDTO();
    formDetailsServices.submitForm(formDTO,firebaseDatabase);
}
@Override
public void onSubmissionSuccess() {
    progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

@Override
public void onSubmissionFailure() {
    progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
}
```

and for FormDetailsServices

```
public class FormDetailsServices {
Context context;
final String TAG = "FormDetailsServices";
OnFormSubmissionListener listener;

public FormDetailsServices(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

public Context getContext() {
    return context;
}

public void setContext(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

void setOnFormSubmissionListener(OnFormSubmissionListener listener){
    this.listener = listener;
}

public void submitForm(FormDTO formDTO,FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase) {

    firebaseDatabase
        .getReference()
        .child("test")
        .setValue(formDTO)
        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {

            Log.d(TAG,"form submitted Successfully");
            
           //here i want to stop progressbar 
            listener.onSubmissionSuccess();
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
        listener.onSubmissionFailure();
            Log.d(TAG,"form submittion Failed exception msg= " + e.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
interface OnFormSubmissionListener { 
     void onSubmissionSuccess();     
     void onSubmissionFailure(); 
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply priyanka, i don't want to stop it from main i want to stop it from FormDetailsService can you provide an example or code for this

Comment: This is the right way to solve your problem. I will edit my comment with code. Just try it.

Comment: Thanks it worked for me.  >>additionally need to make interface named **OnFormSubmissionListener** like this  `public interface OnFormSubmissionListener {
    public void onSubmissionSuccess();
    public void onSubmissionFailure();
}`

Comment: I had added this too. I guess changes were not saved before. Also we do no need to make an interface's methods public.